# min-width take precedence over max-width?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to have the child div start with the defined min-width and then as I add content to that child div, the div will expand till it reaches the max-width? As is, the child div automatically starts out with its max width.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QMf22/

css:

```
#main{
    width:500px;
    min-height:250px;
    background-color: #33363b;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 1% auto;
    overflow: hidden;
} 


#content{
    min-width: 237.5px;
    max-width:490px;
    min-height: 237.5px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 1% auto;
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

html:

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not 100% that I understand your question. At the moment, the content will always be 490px as the parent have a fixed width of 500px.

Comment: Clarifying ? : if max < min then max = min

Comment: The value of the min-width property overrides both max-width and  width. Refer http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-width.asp for additional information.

Comment: @Hoshts I want the child div (the white box) to start at its min-width. Then as content is added, it will expand (the width will grow) until it caps the max-width. But as is, as you see, it automatically starts at the max-width. My question is, how do I get the child div to start with the min-width and then cap at the max-width if the content I add to the child div ever makes it reach that width?

Comment: So just set width to min-width ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<div>` is a block element, and it will wrap it's width equal to it's parent, so your elements won't get the `min-width` nor `max-width` style if the parent container width is bigger or smaller then what you set respectively.

to make the element width depend on the content, you need to use an `inline` element or change the CSS `display` for the `div` to an `inline` element, using

```
display: inline-block
```

here's the updated [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/QMf22/2/)

### UPDATE

if you want to make it in the center, just add CSS

```
text-align: center;
```

inside it's container ( `#main` in your case ), here's the example in [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/QMf22/3/)

Comment: Thanks! Now to have it center?

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/5S9Nt/

try adding

```
#content{
    float: left;
}
```

To the content div.

```
display: inline-block;
```

Would also work. The trick is, the element has to be set to inline somehow.

There are other options, depending on what you want the inner div to look like. Javascript could dynamically force the div (and it's content) to whatever you like.

Media queries might also be useful? The description of the problem is pretty vague.

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {}
```